# WCF OperationContract for both duplex and non-duplex endpoints

Tags: wcf, c#-3.0

I am trying to host a WCF service that supports `wshttpbinding` and `basichttpbinding`. 
The reason is for desktop clients I need duplex and for Windows mobile clients I don't.

Lets say I have 3 OperationContracts, 2 of them need duplex and 1 of them does not.

So is it possible to expose 2 OperationContract with `wsHttpBinding` and the last one with
just `basicHttpBinding`?

Because when I tried I get this error :

> Contract requires Session, but Binding 'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't
>   support it or isn't configured
>   properly to support it.

Is there a way to make this work? Or do I have to make separate WCF services for each binding?

Thanks for advice and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every endpoint always exposes **all** operations for that service that it's representing.

You cannot expose your "basic" endpoint for one method of `Service1`, and your duplex endpoint for the two others.

If you need to be able that kind of flexibility, you need to create two separate service implementations - one that handles the duplex operations, one that handles the others.

Comment: What happens if i change the  [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed, CallbackContract = typeof(IProductionCallback))]. ? instead of SessionMode = SessionMode.Required

Comment: @Tan [Microsoft states that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064(v=vs.110).aspx) "the event-like behavior of duplex services only works within a session", so presumably SessionMode.Allowed would not be a valid configuration, and would not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <endpoint 
         address="ws" 
         binding="wsHttpBinding" 
         contract="YourNamespace.IMyService" />
     <endpoint 
         address="basic" 
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="YourNamespace.IMyService" />
```

Now u can access the service from diff clients using ,

```
http://localhost/ws 
http://localhost/basic,
```

provided, base address is

```
       <host>
           <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
            </baseAddresses>
       </host>
```

If u access using the basic URI, the session will not be created.

Comment: That will not work because windows mobile doesn´t support duplex. And in my operationcontracts i have both duplex and none duplex operations. And i just want when using basichttpbinding expose only operations without duplex.

Comment: This will expose **all three operations** on both endpoints - that will work, but it's not what Tan is looking for....

Comment: Am not sure about simplex communication in basicHttp. 
Please check if this link could be of any use in your case.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/double_simplex_wcf.aspx